# Does Mono ObservableCollection have thread affinity?

Tags: mono, xamarin.forms

I see in documentation and several other places that the Mono `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` is "not thread-safe". I understand that means I shouldn't allow my application to call methods like `Add()` from multiple threads at the same time. But I'm curious if this means it has thread affinity, like Views.

I did WPF work a long time ago, and I remember it had thread affinity in WPF, going so far as throwing a specific exception without getting as far as raising its event. But I've also noticed Xamarin Forms seems to automatically transfer VM property changes to the UI thread when I update bindings, and I don't think WPF did that.

So I set up an example Xamarin.Forms project and bound a `ListView` to an `ObservableCollection`. I wrote some code to add some items on the UI thread, and some code to add them on a worker thread. For comparison, I also wrote a method that sets a Label's text from a worker thread. Both ways to update the ObservableCollection work. Tapping the button that updates the Label crashes the application.

That would *seem* to prove there's no thread affinity, and that Xamarin Forms binding handles the event on the correct thread. But I'm also used to thread affinity problems being somewhat unpredictable, so I could just be "getting lucky".

Is there any definitive answer? Can I update a bound ObservableCollection from any thread, so long as I'm mindful of the separate synchronization issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono ObservableCollection is not thread safe, but has no thread-affinity and shouldn't crash if accessed in a non-concurrent manner, from different threads.